# Make the Question Draft suggestions (requirements) more direct

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, draft

Recently I have been seeing many new questions abide by the first list item in *Step 1: Draft your question*, however those questions also fail horribly at the second two list items.

While unfortunate, I do believe that it is still progress, just that there needs to be an iteration on it.

Here is generally how it seems to play out:

- They draft a question describing their goal and expected outcome.
- They try to explain what they tried and show some code by including a one liner.
- They post.

The problem from the community perspective is now they have technically posted an on topic question, but it is poorly researched. It probably wont be closed, but it will garner several downvotes for lacking research.

From the asker perspective, I believe that the second and third expandable items are not being actioned during question drafting (creation) and as a result they are not really being adhered to enough. This could easily be tested by collecting click rates on those expandable items.

A tenet of asking questions is including research, heck, it even says "this question does not show any research effort" right on the downvote button. The guidance to support that requirement needs to more prominent.

There are two easy ways to increase the prominence of the guidance being given.

**1.**

*Do not hide content, leave the list in full at all times*

The hidden material is so small and compact, yet so useful, it really shouldn't be hidden. When fully expanded it does not reach below the space reserved for asking the question.

Here is a side by side comparison

[image: Fully expanded list items]

**2.**

*Collect expansion data and fully inform users if there was no expansion*

Perhaps this could be an A/B test, or maybe this method is preferable since it ensures that the content was seen.

Collect the button expansion clicks on page during user interaction, and send them along with the question data to review; if one of the sections was not expanded, it would show up as a required issue to resolve.

In red, the non expanded sections could be included below the "*Your question couldn’t be submitted*" note.

[image: Resolve two issues]

This would then force a review of the guidance prior to submitting the question, or, at the very least, highlight the section to the user. It would also provide a data point to look at for question quality in the future; do users who are forced to review a bullet point have a higher propensity for question closure? Lower vote score? etc.

---

In addition to including the prominence of the guidance, I think that the research note is slightly understated. While it is true that showing research will get more answers, it is also deceptive (albeit unintended) because it doesn't inform users that without research they will probably get no answers and probably get downvotes.

The second item in the suggested list reads

> Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

This should perhaps include a nod towards the downvote verbiage. Something along the lines of

> Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you *show your research effort*.

<sub>italics used only to show changed text</sub>

---

**tl;dr;**

Let's do a minor iteration on the Question Draft page in order to highlight the need for showing research when asking.

Comment: This is a good real world example of the type of misunderstanding users are having: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392124/not-understanding-the-downvotes-on-my-questions. Specifically with regards to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070582/wpf-c-sharp-change-a-dll-name. You can see on inspection that the user does the 3 main bullet points, and tries to do the name of the other two without looking at them for details (thus completely missing the note on research, as well missing the MRE link and explanation).

Comment: Well, that certainly explains sentences like "I have just started, I don't have any code" and I "Googled for three days and couldn't find a solution"